# Generating string using obfuscated javascript

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

I saw this neat comment on reddit.

https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/ak026v/aah_yes_c_my_favorite_soft_drink/ef1wi5c

The author makes clever use of javascript statements like:

```
!![]+[]          // 'true'
![]+[]           // 'false'
!![]+![]         // 1
[][!![]+![]]+[]  // 'undefined'
```

to generate strings from these named JS primitives, and the uses array access to build a string (reeeeeeeeee) from them.

I'd love to use this method to troll some friends, but I'd like some more letters.

true, false and undefined yield the letters "d" "n" "s" "f" "e" "a" "t" "i" "r" "l" "u" - is there a way to get other alpha chars? Specifically "p" and "o" but other chars would be cool too?

Comment: ... `"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"` etc. Please narrow your question, since it makes no sense. Do you mean you are limited in the set of input characters to `![]+`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"This is where you can find your answer."*

This in obfuscation is -- (16441 chars)

> [][([+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]]]+(+[()())[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+(+!+[]+[+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(![+!+[]]+([+(+(+!+[]+[+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(![+!+[]]+(!+(![+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]]])()

Refer the link [here](http://www.jsfuck.com/) for more info

Full list of [conversions](https://github.com/aemkei/jsfuck/blob/master/jsfuck.js)